# Listing out searches in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I'm having issues showing out all of my drinks in my index.html.haml. I have recently moved to start using thinking sphinx for searching after watching Ryan Bates' ([thinking sphinx railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx-revised?view=asciicast). As part of the move to sphinx I changed `@drinks = Drink.all` to `@drinks = Drink.search(params[:search])` and now its not showing the drink names on my index page

**Drink Model**

```
class Drink < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :detail, :recipe_steps_attributes

  has_many :recipe_steps, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_steps
  has_one :glass

  validates_uniqueness_of :name, case_sensitive: false

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_steps, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:amount].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  define_index do
    indexes :name
    indexes ingredients.name as: :ingredient_name
  end
end
```

**Drink Controller index**

```
def index
    @drinks = Drink.search(params[:search])
    if current_user
      @cabinet = Cabinet.find(current_user.id)
    end
  end
```

**Drink index.haml**

```
= form_tag drinks_path, method: :get do
  .field
    = text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
    = submit_tag "Search", name: nil

- @drinks.each do |drink|
  = drink.name
```

Comment: Did you run `rake ts:index`? And if you're getting any errors - what are they about?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors from running rake ts:index

I get:

    indexing index 'drink_core'...
    collected 2 docs, 0.0 MB
    sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
    total 2 docs, 16 bytes
    total 0.015 sec, 1018 bytes/sec, 127.33 docs/sec
    skipping non-plain index 'drink'...
    total 3 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
    total 9 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg`

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured this out. I need to re index after the database gets populated with new fields... What is the best way of making sure this happens whenever a new record is added?

Comment: The way I've done it is using crontab to periodically run `rake ts:rebuild`. And you can use the whenever gem to script the cron task when you deploy.

Comment: I personally use `whenever` with `every :hour` setting.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer my own question. The problem was that I hadn't re-indexed after added records to the database. Thus they were not showing up when I was trying to print them out in my block.

As TomL suggested, the best way of dealing with this is to have a cron job periodically run

```
rake ts:rebuild
```